# Requests occasionally stalled

Tags: php, http, apache2

I have a LAMP server and recently I have been getting requests that timeout. When inspecting the request in Chrome the timing tab states that it "Stalled" for 30 seconds. I have no log of the request in the Apache logs and so I'm stuck as to what could be causing it.

I had a look into what "Stalled" could mean and most posts mention having more than 6 simultaneous requests and waiting for an open connection. However the request that is stalling is the html document, so no other requests can be loaded until the document has finished.

Comment: Nothing in apache's `access.log` ?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing in the access.log or vhosts log. Seems to suggest it's not getting as far as Apache.